# Ignoring table in mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, bash

Hi I'm doing a database `copy and paste` from a master to a slave. However there is a table on the slave that I don't want to be overwritten by the master.

I have been trying out the following bash script which is ran via cron job - but it keeps overwriting the slave table I want to ignore. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

#Database login credentials - need to be changed accordingly
dbHost="localhost"

#Master (Staging)
dbMastUser="admin_site"
dbMastName="admin_site_pineapple_master"

#Slave (Live)
dbSlavUser="admin_sync"
dbSlavName="admin_site_pineapple_slave"

dbPass="ExamplePassword"


EXCLUDED_TABLES=(
forms-responses
)

IGNORED_TABLES=''
for TABLE in "${EXCLUDED_TABLES[@]}"
do :
   IGNORED_TABLES+=" --ignore-table=${dbMastName}.${TABLE}"
done

#Update the database from the Master to the Slave
mysqldump -h ${dbHost} -u ${dbMastUser} -p${dbPass} ${dbMastName} ${IGNORED_TABLES} | mysql -h ${dbHost} -u ${dbSlavUser} -p${dbPass} ${dbSlavName}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: set the `localhost` var as `$(localhost)`.

Comment: Refer [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue38/tag/6.html)

Comment: Have you tried the same command by hand? What does this problem have to do with `bash`?

Comment: I would add `set -x` to see if the command is turning out as you expect after all of the substitutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ignoring tables you must use this syntax

```
mysqldump -h {hostname} -u {username} -p{password} --ignore-table test.votes test > E:/db_backups/test_1480080906.sql
```

general syntax

```
mysqldump -h {hostname} -u {username} -p{password} --ignore-table dbname.tbl_name db_name > E:/db_backups/test_1480080906.sql
```

Note : we need to set the options to ignore some tables

Thanks
Suman W.

Comment: Thanks for replying - can you amend your answer to clarify this section "test.votes test"

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -uroot -p{pwd} --skip-lock-tables  --databases f6dms $(mysql -uroot -p{pwd} -Df6dms -Bse "show tables like 'tm_monitor_avg_price_%'"|awk '{print "--ignore-table=f6dms."$1}'|xargs)| gzip > /data/backup/database_f6dms_`date '+%m-%d-%Y'`.sql.gz;
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.